# What does the door want from me?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I am in The Dark and Dank and Sinister Cave, and there is a door that has a shaft like a garbage chute in it! Now, I could just go dropping bits of my stuff in there to see what makes the door open, but I've got some good stuff that I'd rather not feed to a door just in case it's not what the door wants.

So, what kinds of things is the door looking for from me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Good News Everyone!

If the door doesn't like what you feed it, it won't consume the item and you will get the item back. If trial and error/puzzle solving is your thing, go have fun deciphering the door's cryptic clues. If not, read on.

### The solution

[According to kolwiki](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/A_Dark_and_Dank_and_Sinister_Quest), it depends on your class. Your primary stat determines if you are a muscle, mysticality, or moxie class.

**First door:**

> As a muscle class: inserting a viking helmet.
>
> As a mysticality class: inserting a stalk of asparagus.
>
> As a moxie class: inserting some dirty hobo gloves.

**Second door:**

> As a muscle class: inserting an insanely spicy bean burrito.
>
> As a mysticality class: inserting an insanely spicy enchanted bean burrito.
>
> As a moxie class: inserting an insanely spicy jumping bean burrito.

**Third Door:**

> As a Seal Clubber: inserting a clown whip.
>
> As a Turtle Tamer: inserting a clownskin buckler.
>
> As a Pastamancer: inserting some boring spaghetti.
>
> As a Sauceror: inserting a tomato juice of powerful power.
>
> As a Disco Bandit: inserting a fruity girl drink, other than a swill or a pumpkin beer.
>
> As an Accordion Thief: Buffing yourself with the Polka of Plenty.

**Final door:**

> Collect the 8 paper strips from enemies in A Large Chamber, then reorder them by matching up the torn edges to spell the password for the A Big Door. Note that vertical tears aren't necessarily borders, but might connect to each other. The password is entered as one word, no spaces between strips.

Comment: One thing that could be integrated in the answer is that the door always gives you a cryptic suggestion regarding the item you're supposed to insert.